# Java reading information from a website using Jsoup

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I've gone through multiple posts about parsing and such. Most of the responses that I saw were recommending the person to use a Library or something else. My problem right now is creating an algorithm that will fetch the exact information I want. My purpose for this is to fetch 2 statuses from the Weather website for school closings. I started using Jsoup as someone recommended but I need help with it.

Webpage: [Click here](http://www.10tv.com/content/sections/weather/closings.html)

Image: [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLZ32.png)

Example of webpage source: [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fo3G.png)

I could probably figure out how to get a certain line of text within the webpage since I already know the name of the school im looking for, but 2 lines down is the status which is what I need. would be easy if each school had a certain status but they are all either Closed or Two-hour Delay so I can't just make a search for that. I want some ideas or answers on how i can apporach this. I am going to do this 2 times because I am wanting to look up 2 schools. I already have the names which I can use to look them up I just need the status.

Here is an example of what I want to do. (sudo code)

```
Document doc = connect(to url);
Element schoolName1 = doc.lookForText(htmlLineHere/schoolname);

String status1 = schoolName.getNext().text();//suppose this gets the line right after which should be my status and then cleans off the Html.
```

This is what I have right now

```
public static SchoolClosing lookupDebug() throws IOException {
        final ArrayList<String> Status = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            //connects to my wanted website
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.10tv.com/content/sections/weather/closings.html").get();
            //selects/fetches the line of code I want
            Element schoolName = doc.html("<td valign="+"top"+">Athens City Schools</td>");
            //an array of Strings where I am going to add the text I need when I get it
            final ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
            //checking if its fetching the text
            System.out.println(schoolName.text());
            //add the text to the array
            temp.add(schoolName.text());
            for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
                final String[] tempStatus = temp.get(i).split(" ");
                Status.add(tempStatus[0]);
            }
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            throw new IOException("There was a problem loading School Closing Status");
        }
        return new SchoolClosing(Status);
    }
```

Comment: Any assistance will help please!

Comment: all the people asking questions here would like some kind of assistance to their problem. No need to shout it.

Comment: I apologize, is that it hasn't gotten any attention and I posted this yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(
        "http://www.10tv.com/content/sections/weather/closings.html")
        .get();
for (Element tr : doc.select("#closings tr")) {
    Element tds = tr.select("td").first();
    if (tds != null) {
        String county = tr.select("td:eq(0)").text();
        String schoolName = tr.select("td:eq(1)").text();
        String status = tr.select("td:eq(2)").text();
        System.out.println(String.format(
                "county: %s, schoolName: %s, status: %s", county,
                schoolName, status));
    }
}
```

output:

```
county: Athens, schoolName: Beacon School, status: Two-hour Delay
county: Franklin, schoolName: City of Grandview Heights, status: Snow Emergency through 8pm Thursday
county: Franklin, schoolName: Electrical Trades Center, status: All Evening Activities Cancelled
county: Franklin, schoolName: Hilock Fellowship Church, status: PM Services Cancelled
county: Franklin, schoolName: International Christian Center, status: All Evening Activities Cancelled
county: Franklin, schoolName: Maranatha Baptist Church, status: PM Services Cancelled
county: Franklin, schoolName: Masters Commission New Covenant Church, status: Bible Study Cancelled
county: Franklin, schoolName: New Life Christian Fellowship, status: All Activities Cancelled
county: Franklin, schoolName: The Epilepsy Foundation of Central Ohio, status: All Evening Activities Cancelled
county: Franklin, schoolName: Washington Ave United Methodist Church, status: All Evening Activities Cancelled
```

or in a loop:

```
for (Element tr : doc.select("#closings tr")) {
    System.out.println("----------------------");
    for (Element td : tr.select("td")) {
        System.out.println(td.text());
    }
}
```

that gives:

```
----------------------
Athens
Beacon School
Two-hour Delay
----------------------
Franklin
City of Grandview Heights
Snow Emergency through 8pm Thursday
----------------------
Franklin
Electrical Trades Center
All Evening Activities Cancelled
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the magnificant answer! Wish I could express how thankful I am. I can do what I need since you formatted it perfectly.

Comment: This is what im making, its a snapchat of my program.
http://i.imgur.com/geEalQK.png